# Adsense not showing

Tags: adsense

I'm using react in my app to show adsense ads but they don't appear. I'm using them on a HTML5 game, so there is no content on the page, just canvas.

This has been approved a few hours ago. Might be a reason?

I'm seeing this error: `"TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: Only one 'enable_page_level_ads' allowed per page.`, but this should not affect.

My static HTML page ending:

```
    <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:1000px;height:90px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXX"
         data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXX"></ins>
    <script>
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My react component:

```
export const AdsenseBlock: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    try {
      (window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  })
  return (
    <ins className="adsbygoogle"
         style={{'display': 'inline-block', width: '1000px', height: '90px'}}
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXX"
         data-ad-slot="XXXXXXX"></ins>
  )
}
```

This is how th HTML looks like after I execute my code. Note how the 2nd iframe body is empty. I guess it should have something.

[image]

In adsense report I see 101 page views and 0 impressions.

[image]

How I created the ad:

[image]

[image]

Also my domain is approved, and added subdomain:

[image]

What I tried:

- sub.domain.com/ads.txt and domain.com/ads.txt contains the `google.com, pub-XXXXXXXXXXX, DIRECT, XXXXXXXXXXXX` (also contain AdinPlay.com ads.txt, does this affect?)
- Disabled ad blocker
- Tried in incognito and on other devices
- Ads are approved in adsense. Also added the subdomain

I also tried to create a new empty page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXX"></ins>
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but ads still not showing. I literally copy pasted the code from adsense

What else can I do?

Comment: Do you have AdBlock enabled?

Comment: No, I disabled. Please check the "What I tried:" list in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Suddenly the ads appeared today. I guess you need to wait. Adsense still shows data from yesteday. I guess we need to wait a bit.

Comment: I also added responsive ad today on my web page but its been 8 hours no ad is displayed yet. Hopefully, it will show automatically after 24 hours.